# Find repeated data from index and string it together

Tags: r

Using R, if I have a 2 column data frame:

```
meta <- c(1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5)
value <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
df <- data.frame(meta,value)
df
  meta value
1    1     a
2    2     b
3    2     c
4    3     d
5    4     e
6    4     f
7    4     g
8    5     h
```

How would I go about combining "value" with a delimiter (like ||) by repeated "meta" such that the resulting data frame would look like:

```
  meta   value
1    1       a
2    2    b||c
3    3       d
4    4 e||f||g
5    5       h
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `plyr` package the following works

```
library(plyr)
> ldply(split(df,meta),function(x){paste(x$value,collapse="||")})
  .id      V1
1   1       a
2   2    b||c
3   3       d
4   4 e||f||g
5   5       h
```

or

```
> ddply(df,.(meta),function(x){c(value=paste(x$value,collapse="||"))})
  meta   value
1    1       a
2    2    b||c
3    3       d
4    4 e||f||g
5    5       h
```

if you want to preserve names

Answer (score 4):

Slightly different, fairly lean, and in base:

```
y <- split(df$value, df$meta)
data.frame(meta=names(y), value=sapply(y, paste, collapse="||"))
```

or even simpler:

```
aggregate(value~meta, df, paste, collapse="||")
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope you don't dislike one liners:   data.frame(meta=unique(df$meta),    value=sapply(unique(df$meta), function(m){ paste(df$value[which(df$meta==m)],collapse="||")  })  )

```
> data.frame(meta=unique(df$meta),    value=sapply(unique(df$meta), function(m){ paste(df$value[which(df$meta==m)],collapse="||")  })  )
  meta   value
1    1       a
2    2    b||c
3    3       d
4    4 e||f||g
5    5       h
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way...

```
 uni.meta <- unique(df$meta)
    list <- lapply(1:length(uni.meta),function(x) which(df$meta==uni.meta[x]))
    new.value <- unlist(lapply(1:length(list),function(x) paste(df$value[list[[x]]],collapse="||")))
new.df <- data.frame(uni.meta,new.value)

new.df
  uni.meta new.value
1        1         a
2        2      b||c
3        3         d
4        4   e||f||g
5        5         h
```